# Display account details on new tab

Tags: outputlink

for displaying account or opportunity details on new tab i used link but tht was hard-coded, so i want it should be dynamic.plz someone help me.

0}">

```
                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                   <apex:outputLink value="https://ap5.lightning.force.com/{!o.opp.Id}" target="_blank">{!o.opp.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="AccountName" >
                    <apex:outputLink value="https://ap5.lightning.force.com/{!o.opp.AccountId}" target="_blank">{!selectedAcc}</apex:outputLink>

                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="CloseDate">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!o.opp.CloseDate}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Type">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!o.opp.Type}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Amount">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!o.opp.Amount}"/>
```

Comment: Use relative navigation like: value="/{!o.opp.Id}". Be awarw that this won't work properly/natively in Salesforce1, lightning and consoles; only in classic.

Comment: thnkss rahul.....its working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid hardcoding, use relative URL like:

```
value="/{!o.opp.Id}"
```

Note: this would only work in classic. For supporting in Salesforce1, lightning and console, you would have yo use different JavaScript APIs for navigation.

Comment: For lightning make sure you use the new url format
http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_general_enhanced_urls_cruc.htm#rn_general_enhanced_urls_cruc